# INSERT statement doesn't work in WEB SERVER

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

IN  localhost insert statement WORKS PERFECTLY ( insert data in database sql management server) but from web server it doesn't ( update, delete works but not insert).

I am using sql connection , string str = insert into dtbase.dbo.candidat values (). 
command cmd = new command (sql, connection)

Can someone please tell me why it doesn;t work from wb server ( I am using web application.) do i need to add some permision in web.config?

Comment: Most likely a permissions issue. But you may want to pos some code or describe your infrastructure. It is really weird that it lets you delete but not insert. Does it shows an error?

Comment: If you were missing some permission to insert you'd get an exception. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Turn on profiler and see what it is sending.

Comment: Uncommitted transaction? Maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if this is a permissions issue (which I think it is) or not then ***temporarily*** (this is for the down voters out there) enable ASP.Net Impersonation by using an account that you know has access to your network and SQL Server instance: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

Comment: -1: can you find a modern version of the article you linked to? That one is almost a decade old.

Comment: I don't get any exception. Even if i change the insert statement as : string str = 'insert into database.dbo.table values () " to string str = insert into table values() " i don't get any error. Though, on local host if I do that, i have an error saying table does not exist ( but on server it doesn't with either one.Checking result, with bug tracker it post ok to the method). i\ll will put some code ( but the problem is not from the code)

Comment: @JohnSaunders the second link was updated September 22, 2011, is that not recent enough for you?

Comment: The problem with posting .NET 1.1 links is that people will click on the links within the articles, leading to more .NET 1.1 links. Before they know it, they're led to more and more obsolete information. Simply edit your answer to include a current link, and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @JohnSaunders then why is wrong with using information in the first link to temporarily "turn on" impersonation? BTW I removed the "offending" link.

Comment: The information may be accurate, but the information it _links to_ may not be. Simply find the current version of the link and update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other comments, I agree that it sounds like a permissions issue.

You may be getting the error using `database.dbo.table` because your table was created under a different schema (ie. `database.user.table`) and you're trying to access that schema from a user that doesn't have permissions to that schema.

Does your connection string change from localhost to your production server?